# System.Net.Cookiecontainer does not handle expires time correctly

Tags: .net, cookies, system.net, cookiecontainer

piece of code to talk about.

```
        var client = new RestClient(URL);
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        var loginRequest = new RestRequest(loginURL, Method.GET);
        RestResponse response = (RestResponse) client.Execute(loginRequest);
        foreach (RestResponseCookie c in response.Cookies)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(c.Value.ToString()+"\n");

        }
```

When the set-cookie header sent from server looks like this:

> Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; Path=/; expires=Mon, 23 Sep 2033 21:17:15 -0000

Everything is fine and cookie remains set, and its value is appended to richTextBox1. However if set-cookie looks like this:

> Set-Cookie: request_method=POST; Path=/; expires=Mon, 23 Sep 2033 21:17:15 **UTC**

It does not work - cookie is not being set. When i checked it on a Google chrome, it being set correctly even with UTC. Why is that happening?